# Executing TSQL batch multiple times through dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL SERVER 2017 (Developper Edition 64 Bit) on a Windows 10 Machine. I'm trying to execute in a dynamic sql a batch multiples times through GO and it won't work.
But the sql Statement will work if it is not execute dynamically. The goal is to do it dynamically and I still don't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is how the definition tables look like:

```
ParentTable

(

Id uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) not null,

Created datetime not null,

Creator uniqueidentifier not null,

Modifier uniqueidentifier null,

Modified datetime null

)

ChildTable

(

Id uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) not null,

ParentTable_Id not null,

Created datetime not null,

Creator uniqueidentifier not null,

Modifier uniqueidentifier null,

Modified datetime null
)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
create Procedure InsertIntoChildTable
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @countDset int
DECLARE @todaysdate datetime
DECLARE @UserName uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @ParentTable_Id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @insertIntoChildTable nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ChildTableName nvarchar(35)

SET @ChildTableName = ChildTable
SET @countDset = 6
SET @todaysdate = GETDATE()
SET @UserName = 'e86aacf4-9887-e911-9724-4439c492b2a7'

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @insertIntoChildTable = 'INSERT INTO ' + @ChildTableName + ' 
(ParentTable_Id, Created, Creator, Modified, Modifier)
VALUES ( (select max(Id) from ParentTable) , @todaysdate, @UserName , 
NULL, NULL) ' + ' GO ' + @countDset

EXECUTE sp_executesql @insertIntoChildTable,N'@ChildTableName 
nvarchar(35), @todaysdate datetime, @UserName uniqueidentifier, 
@countDset int', @ChildTableName = @ChildTableName, @todaysdate = 
@todaysdate, @UserName = @UserName, @countDset = @countDset

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'Could not insert in the Child table'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION      
RETURN
END CATCH

END
```

After the Line with 'Go ' + @countDset it will automatically go into the Catch block and return.

Thank you

Comment: `GO` is a SSMS/`sqlcmd` keyword, not a T-SQL keyword; you can't use it in dynamic SQL.

Comment: A `GO [x]` statement in SSMS makes it manually loop `x` times executing the statement; you can emulate that behavior in T-SQL with your own manual loop, but you really don't want to, given how ridiculously inefficient it is. Use a numbers table and an `INSERT ... SELECT` to insert all the rows at once.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem like something you want to use dynamic SQL for - Doesn't seem like the `@ChildTableName` need to be a variable as it's value is hard coded in the procedure anyway... Instead of `go 6` you can use a while loop or better yet, use a cross join to insert  6 rows in one statement.

Comment: For testpurposes I used a while loop to insert the same values 6 times and it worked perfectly. But in the productive system I have to insert at least 3000 rows at once and with a while loop it won't be that effective. @ZoharPeled Using a cross join to insert the 6 rows? I' m afraid I don't understand

Comment: [Here's a quick example.](https://rextester.com/HFG22922)

Comment: As Zohar is indicating, you need to think "set based" with your code here. There's no need for dynamic sql or while loops here.

Comment: Well you should consider posting an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted (when the system lets you do that) or simply delete the question.

Comment: I was about to mark you answer as accepted but I just can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ChildTable ( ParentTable_Id, Created, Creator, Modified, Modifier )
SELECT (select max(Id) from ParentTable) as ParentId , @todaysdate, @UserName , 
NULL, NULL
FROM
( 
SELECT TOP @countDset '' As Dummy
FROM sys.Objects As A
CROSS JOIN sys.Objects As B
) As Multiplier
```

Guided through the example Zohar posted I could insert new Rows in the ChildTable using CROSS JOIN